# Balancing panel containing dates with R

Tags: r, dplyr, plm

The use of dates in plm prevents it from balancing the panel with the make.pbalanced function:

```
State <- c("alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama",
          "california", "california", "maine", "kansas")
Date <- c("2021-01-25", "2021-01-26", "2021-01-27", "2021-01-28",
            "2021-01-25", "2021-01-30", "2021-01-25", "2021-01-27")
Number <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
            'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')    

df_state = data.frame(State, Date, Number) 

head(df_state)

       State       Date Number
1    alabama 2021-01-25      a
2    alabama 2021-01-26      b
3    alabama 2021-01-27      c
4    alabama 2021-01-28      d
5 california 2021-01-25      e
6 california 2021-01-30      f
```

When you try to balance the panel, you get the following error:

```
df_state$Date = anydate(df_state$Date)
df_state = pdata.frame(df_state, index = c("State","Date"))
df_state_balanced = make.pbalanced(df_state, balance.type = "fill")
```

**Error in seq.default(from = min_value, to = max_value, by = 1) : 'from' must be a finite number**

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: I think for `balance.type = "fill"` the date variable must be interpretable as integer